# Composer installed for Drupal Crashes

Tags: windows, drupal, composer-php, drupal-9

I had a perfectly running composer installed with launcher on my drupal project directory. It was working fine until I came back after a month's break to start working on my project again. To my surprise, when I open the composer from the directory where it is installed, the command prompt opens but automatically kills (Blink some texts & closes) it self in a second.

Could someone please advise me what could be going wrong in here.

Comment: What do you mean by "open the composer"?

Comment: I actually fixed this error. I was trying to open the launcher from the directory by Composer instead of cmd. When I used cmd to open the composer console it worked fine.